# Replacing Non-Breaking Space Android not working

Tags: android, unicode, replace, whitespace, replaceall

I need to replace `\u00A0`, but it doesn't work with (found out which character it is by copying it to a text to unicode converter)

```
string.replace("\u00A0", " ");
```

It also doesn't work with copying the exakt character from the log into  Android Studio. I unfortunately can't paste this character here, it gets converted to a normal white space.

I also tried many other solutions which should potentially remove this character, none of them actually worked.

My intention is to compare two phone numbers (looking like this: +49 176 34535...), one with non-breaking spaces and one with normal whitespaces from the keyboard. Non-breaking spaces result of reading the phone number from a notification.

Does someone have an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: why have you doubled the backslash?

Comment: @bobince Doens't it has to be double-slashed? Whatever, it unfortunately doesn't work in any way with this unicode, if double-slashed or with only one.

Comment: You double up a backslash only when you want an actual backslash character in a literal. `"\\u00A0"` is 5 characters, a single backslash character followed by `'0'` `'0'` `'A'` `'0'`, whereas `"\u00A0"` is only 1 character, a non-break space.  If the code is not working for you, please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are using it. For instance, `replaceAll()` does not modify the `String` it is called on, it returns a new `String`. Are you accounting for that? Also note that the first parameter is a **Regular Expression**, and backslash has special meaning in a regex expression.

Comment: If you don't actually need to use regex, you should use `String.replace()` instead of `String.replaceAll()`, eg: `String s = ...; s = s.replace('\u00A0', ' ');`

Comment: Edited the post, tried everything without success. That's strange. I'm confused why it doesn't work, that's why I don't have any plan anymore how many backslashes I have to use ;)

Comment: I'm using string = string.replace("\u00A0", " ");
That always worked